# How to compare first and second rows of an array using C

Tags: c, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, compare

I have a 2d array mat[5][10] and i am trying to find out if the first row contains the same elements as the second (using C). But i could not figure out how to do it in C. Here is my code and its not working

```
char mat[5][10] = { "Java", "Python", "C++", "HTML", "SQL" };

if(mat[0][10] == mat[1][10])
{
    printf("YESSS");
}
else
{
    printf("NOOO");
}
```

Comment: You must compare the individual elements of the sub-arrays.  Or since they are all strings, make use of `strcmp`.

Comment: what do you think is `mat[0][10]` on your example ?

Comment: i took mat[0][10] as the first row and mat[1][10] as the second row

Comment: What is your understanding of "row". Please explain in terms of the example what you think "first row" and "second row" are supposed to correspond to.

Comment: `mat[0]` is the first row. `mat[0][0]` is the first character of the first row. `mat[0][10]` is not valid because the second index must be a number between 0 and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell from your explanation, you want to compare the first element of a char array with other elements. I wrote a suitable code for this. You can examine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define  length(x) (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))
int main() {
    
    char mat[5][10] = {"Java", "Python", "Java", "HTML", "SQL"};
    
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i < length(mat); ++i) {
        if(!strcmp(mat[0], mat[i])) {
            printf("Yes");
            break;
        }
    }
    if(i == length(mat)) {
        printf("No");
    }
}
```